# How to host eclipse plugins(cheatsheet)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have developed a eclipse plugin (cheatsheet), packaged in jar format. Can anyone tell me how to host that plugin publicily or in tomcat server so that remote user can install it through the given URL, using the Install Software menu ?

I don't want to copy that plugin in eclipse's plugin folder i want to install that...

Answer (score 3):

You have to create an update site for that. Here is the [Eclipse tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_update_site_(site.xml)%3F) for creating an update site.

Comment: thanks, Can u tell me how to use URL to install like http://www.plugin-example.com is my site. how to install through that???

Comment: @Rahul : from what I can see in the link, you just have to create a update.xml file, put it with the jar on a ftp, and that's it

Comment: Here's a link that worked for me: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_update_site_%28site.xml%29%3F